# switch images with onclick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials, locals

I have a partial called _avatar.html.erb
I want to pass in an id as a local variable called entity_id which will be the id of an object.

```
<% form_tag({:controller => "avatar", :action => "upload", :id => entity_id}, :multipart => true ) do %>
        <fieldset>
        <legend><%= title %></legend>
        <% if avatar.exists? %>
        <%= avatar_tag(avatar) %>
[<%= link_to "delete", {:controller => "avatar",:action => "delete", :id => entity_id},:confirm => "Are you sure" %>]
         ...
```

Here is the call for the parital:

```
<%= render :partial => 'avatar/avatar', :locals => {:avatar => @avatar, :title => @title, :entity_id => @board.id } %>
```

When I try this I get the following errors:

undefined local variable or method `entity_id' for #

When I take that out I also get an error telling me it can't find the local variable "title".

Can anyone help this seems to be the correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the error is coming from the partial?  You are using `entity_id` in the `form_tag`.  Where is it being defined?  `title` isn't used in the partial.  It is used inside of `legend` though.  Is that defined?

Comment: I fixed the problem. I had some strange ghost in my machine. I restarted it and it all works now.